# broadcast groupby with boolean filter scalar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame according to below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : list('a' * 3) + list('b' * 2) + list('c' * 4) 
         ,'var2' : [i for i in range(9)]
         ,'var3' : [20, 40, 100, 10, 80, 12,24, 53, 90]
     })
```

End result that I want is the following:

```
  var1 var2 var3  var3_lt_50
0   a   0   20    60
1   a   1   40    60
2   a   2   100   60
3   b   3   10    10
4   b   4   80    10
5   c   5   12    36
6   c   6   24    36
7   c   7   53    36
8   c   8   90    36
```

I get this result in two steps, through a group-by and a merge, according to code below:

```
df = df.merge(df[df.var3 < 50][['var1', 'var3']].groupby('var1', as_index = False).sum().rename(columns = {'var3' : 'var3_lt_50'})
         ,how = 'left'
         ,left_on = 'var1'
         ,right_on = 'var1')
```

Can someone show me a way of doing this type of boolean logic expression + broadcasting of inter groupby scalar without the "groupby" + "merge" step im doing today. I want a smoother line of code.

Thanks in advance for input,

/Swepab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` which keeps the shape of the transformed variable as well as the index so you can just assign the result back to the data frame:

```
df['var3_lt_50'] = df.groupby('var1').var3.transform(lambda g: g[g < 50].sum())
df
```

[image]

Comment: "And Bobs ur uncle" - Thanks!

Comment: A quick follow-up questions: If I wanted to change the boolean expression to another variable than the one I sum, how would that change the code? Just for example, say that I want to sum where var2 > 4, and broadcast that back to all group-bys in the same fashion as the example

Comment: You can use `assign` in `groupby.apply`,  which is functional and has the ability to broadcast scalar value. Something like `df.groupby('var1', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.assign(new_var = g.var3[g.var2 > 3].sum()))`